# is it possible to copy the value of bitset<8> to a string of arrays without converting them?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, binary

I tried `char a[9]=bitset<8>(f[1])`
but as many of you know that did not work.
i want to copy the binary value to an array so basically if `f[1]` will be 'a'
 the `char a` will be 01100001

And also , this is not a duplication the question asked before was not what I searched.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a string of arrays, and how the bits in the bitfield would map to entries in that "string"?

Comment: What is `f`'s type?  Maybe [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)?

Comment: `char f[256]` this is the type of f

Answer (score 1):

You can't direct-initialize an array from an object. You'll need to define the array an then initialize it. Even then, sadly, `std::bitset<...>` doesn't provide iterators to allow use of `std::transform()` to fill in the characters. However, a with a simple auxiliary function the initialization can be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
template <std::size_t Size>
void initialize(char (&array)[Size], std::bitset<Size - 1> bits) {
    for (std::size_t idx(0); idx != Size - 1; ++idx) {
         array[idx] = '0' + bits[idx];
    }
    array[Size-1] = 0;
}

int main(int, char* av[]) {
    char a[9];
    initialize(a, av[0][0]);
    std::cout << "array=" << a << '\n';
}
```